# Realizar ação em todas as textboxes sem precisar repetir para cada uma (C#)

Tags: c#, desempenho, textbox

Bom,eu tenho um programa Windows Form com 35 textboxes,e quero realizar a seguinte ação em todas elas,mas sem precisar repetir o código pra cada uma delas:

```
    private void txtGSabado5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGSabado5.Text))
        {
            txtGSabado5.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            txtGSabado5.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

Ou seja,se a textbox estiver vazia ela muda a cor de fundo para vermelho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem vindo à comunidade!

Você pode percorrer cada controle do `Form` através da propriedade [Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Controls). Então, para cada item, você define um [EventHandler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/#event-handlers) que executará a lógica que você deseja:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach(Control control in Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            control.TextChanged += Control_TextChanged;
        }
    }
}

private void Control_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Como o parâmetros sender é do tipo object,
    // precisamos fazer um cast para o tipo de objeto do TextBox
    // Então, poderemos definir as propriedades dele
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox) sender;
    
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
    {
        textBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```